# How to call WebMethod inside Class file using Angularjs?

Tags: c#, angularjs, webmethod

I am calling `WebMethod` using `angularjs` call. I got response when `WebMethod` inside  **.aspx.cs** but **not** getting response if  `WebMethod` inside **class file**(class1.cs).

Call return **403 Forbidden** error.

Class file::

```
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;

public class done
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string test()
  {
      string x = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/live.json");
      return x;
  }
}
```

How to get **response** when **WebMethod** inside **class file**.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I had issues using WebMethod in .cs files as it is normally used for aspx.cs files. Instead I used HttpPost attribute in my .cs file. I haven't used AngularJS (jQuery guy here) but I can imagine it would have the same issue. This is how I solved my error if you still need help.

CS Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ReturnType MethodName(ParamType param1, ParamType param1)
    {
       obj = new ReturnType();
       // do something
       return obj;
    }
```

Ajax call

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("MethodName", "Contoller")",
        //if not MVC, just <path to file>/MethodName
        error: function () {
            console.log("=(");
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log("hi");
        }
    })
```

Hopefully this helps you!